# How do you set DEBUG or RELEASE builds in Visual Studio 2008 (VB.net)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vb.net

I have Visual Studio 2008 and am developing VB.NET applications.

How do I specify if I am building a debug or release version?  [The description I found of how to do this on the Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) don't seem to be accurate. This should be pretty straightforward shouldn't it?  It seems that a friend of mine who does C# development says it is easy in his environment.  Are the VS environments different between C# and VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think maybe I finally figured it out.  I swear I looked for this before and it was never there, but if I right click on the solution, the "configuration manager" item appears.  That seems to be how I set the debug/release compile options.  The other option is to go to the "Build" menu and it shows up there too.  I'm not sure why I didn't see that before.